# Is it possible to pass a method of another class to a function?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

I have a 2D cell array(Cell[,] _map) and methods:

```
private void OpenNearCells(Vector2Int cellCoordinates)
{
    for (int i = cellCoordinates.Y - 1; i <= cellCoordinates.Y + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = cellCoordinates.X - 1; j <= cellCoordinates.X + 1; j++)
        {
            if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= Height || j >= Width)
                continue;

            _map[i, j].Open();
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
private void NotifyNearCells(Vector2Int bombCoordinates)
{
    for (int i = bombCoordinates.Y - 1; i <= bombCoordinates.Y + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = bombCoordinates.X - 1; j <= bombCoordinates.X + 1; j++)
        {
            if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= Height || j >= Width)
                continue;

            _map[i, j].Notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Vector2Int is just a structure containing fields for the x and y coordinates.

I know about delegates a little, but my methods (Cell.Open and Cell.Notify) are in another class and they need to do some actions with the specific member of the class. So I want to do smth like this:

```
private void DoNearCellsAction(Function action, Vector2Int centerCellCoordinates)
{
    for (int i = cellCoordinates.Y - 1; i <= cellCoordinates.Y + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = cellCoordinates.X - 1; j <= cellCoordinates.X + 1; j++)
        {
            if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= Height || j >= Width)
                continue;

            _map[i, j].action();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it somehow possible to create a method like this or is it exist another way to avoid repeating code? What does this syntax look like?

Comment: You are looking for `Action<Cell> action`, use as `action(_map[i, j])`

Comment: Please avoid answering in the comments.

Comment: Read up on `Delegate`s in the .NET world.  They are very useful in many situations.  Also look up `Action` (and `Action<T...>` ) and `Func` (and `Func<T...>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  Taking a simplified version of your class:

```
public class Cell 
{
   public void Notify(Vector2Int vector) { }
   public void Open(Vector2Int vector) { }
}
```

You could create `Action`s of the same signature that house those:

```
Action<Cell, Vector2Int> notifyAction = (cell, vector) => cell.Notify(vector);
Action<Cell, Vector2Int> openAction = (cell, vector) => cell.Open(vector);
```

Then your method would look something like:

```
private void DoNearCellsAction(Action<Cell, Vector2Int> action, Vector2Int centerCellCoordinates)
{
    action(_map[i, j], centerCellCoordinates)
}
```